# Golden Ratio example not satisfying ratio

Tags: golden-ratio

Golden ratio says $\frac{a}{b}=\frac{a+b}{a}$ and it shows up in rectangle also.  If we take rectangle of $a=4$ and $b=2$. then $\frac{a}{b}=\frac{4}{2}=2$ and $\frac{a+b}{a}=\frac{4+2}{4}=\frac{6}{4}=1.5$. But $1.5 \ne 2$, how does this hold true?

Comment: Because it is not a golden rectangle!

Answer (score 1):

Golden rectangle is a rectangle with side ratio  $1 : \frac{\sqrt{5} +1}{2} $ , not any arbitrary rectangle.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're confused because you are thinking both $a$ AND $b$ are independent variables you can arbitrarily set. A golden rectangle is any rectangle whose side lengths $a$ and $b$ satisfy
$$ \frac{a}{b} = \frac{a+b}{a} $$
If you decide to set $a = 2$, then $b$ must be restricted if you want the above equation to hold true. In fact, you'd get
\begin{align}
\frac{2}{b} &= \frac{b+2}{2} \\
b(b+2) &= 4 \\
b^2 + 2b - 4 &= 0
\end{align}
Using the quadratic formula:
\begin{align}
b &= \frac{-2 + \sqrt{2^2-4(1)(-4)}}{2} \\
&= \frac{-2 + \sqrt{20}}{2} \\
&= \frac{-2 + 2\sqrt{5}}{2} \\
&= \sqrt{5} - 1
\end{align}
Hence we get
\begin{align}
\frac{a}{b} &= \frac{2}{\sqrt{5}-1} \\
&= \frac{2(\sqrt{5}+1)}{5-1} \\
&= \frac{2(\sqrt{5}+1)}{4} \\
&= \frac{\sqrt{5}+1}{2}
\end{align}
which is the Golden Ratio.